# Import static jQuery JS file using Webjars and Spark

Tags: java, webjars

I'm using Spark as framework to build a Java web server and rely on Bootstrap and jQuery for frontend. I'm using [Webjars](http://www.webjars.org/) to bring dependencies in my `pom.xml`.

The problem omes with importing static files. While importing Bootstrap's CSS and JS files works well, it doesn't for jQuery JS file. I import the static files using `staticFileLocation("/META-INF/resources");` and HTML header contains:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

`webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css` and `webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js` routes work well but `webjars/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js` answers 404.

Somehow, it looks like jQuery JS file isn't present in classpath. Any clue what I'm missing ?

### Edit:

The `pom.xml` dependencies are the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

### Edit 2:

I also call `staticFileLocation()` two times in my controller:

```
staticFileLocation("/static");
staticFileLocation("/META-INF/resources");
```

The two calls seem to conflict with each other.

Comment: Not sure, but I think apache-spark is the wrong tag - if by "Spark" you're referring to http://sparkjava.com/, then remove apache-spark tag, which refers to a different project (http://spark.apache.org/)

Comment: Hmm... Spark tag is automatically turned into apache-spark. Thx for highlight.

Comment: What does your jquery dependency in the `pom.xml` look like?

Answer (score 1):

The `jquery` version `2.2.1` dependency is probably being overridden via a transitive dependency on `jquery` in `bootstrap`.  You can either set an exclusion in the `bootstrap` dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
  <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.6</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
      <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions> 
</dependency>
```

Or you can remove the explicit dependency on `jquery` and use the transitive one which is `1.11.1` per the [bootstrap pom.xml](https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.webjars%7Cbootstrap%7C3.3.6%7Cjar).

Comment: None of your solutions do work. The problem remains: jquery.min.js is not linked.

Comment: You need to find out what version of the jquery dependency is being pulled into the classpath.  You can do that via a variety of ways like with https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

I've found that if you run Spark from an IDE which is used `mvn exec:exec` to run project then you get only bootstrap in `/META-INF/resources/webjars`.

But if you make a [jar-with-dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/574650/2775220) first and then run it with `java -jar <your-project-name-and-version>-jar-with-dependencies.jar` you'll get whole set of resources (both bootstrap and jquery in your case).

Actually you can easily check available resources with this code:

```
get("/list", (req, res) -> {
    Resource resource = Resource.newClassPathResource("/META-INF/resources");
    return resource.getListHTML("/", true);
});
```

Accessing `/list` you will get whole list of available resources.

Answer (score 0):

Diving into Spark's source code, I found that one can refer to only one static folder location. Hence, only one webjar can be used at the same time and it will make Spark to ignore any CSS or JS file in any other location.